# Bootstrap 3: how to 7 images in 12 columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, web

I just joined StackOverflow since I recently got back to webdesign and I'm learning Bootstrap. I'm designing my own Website and I'm already facing an issue that I can't resolve myself. I want to achieve the following: [Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfq1u.png) I also would like to make the arrows disappear when the screen size gets so small that make the icons look in a vertical way instead of the regular horizontal way (hope I explained it correctly)

I already tried some things and failed:

1- Instead of using each icon/arrow in a separate img file, I saved them in a unique img file and used the *css "img-responsive" class*. It looked pretty good on desktop but text looked too small on mobile.

2- After that I got back to trying to make it work with each img in a separate file, I found a post here about getting 7 equal columns and it seems to do what I need but I can't get the images to be close enough as I want to, tried several ways to remove the gutter between the columns and nothing, I think that it might be cause to get the 7 equal columns, the columns itself get a fixed width, not allowing me to get rid of their padding/margin.

Here's what I've got so far:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="whyus" class="container-fluid text-center">
    <h2>Why Us?</h2>
        <div class="row seven-cols">
            <div class="col-md-1 no-padding">
                <img src="img/Heart_icon.png">
                <h4>Passion</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 no-padding">
                <img src="img/Arrow1.png" class="arrow1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 no-padding">
                <img src="img/Idea_icon.png">
                <h4>Ideas</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 no-padding">
                <img src="img/Arrow2.png" class="arrow2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 no-padding">
                <img src="img/Brain_icon.png">
                <h4>Work</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 no-padding">
                <img src="img/Arrow1.png" class="arrow1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 no-padding">
                <img src="img/Like_icon.png">
                <h4>Amazing Results</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.arrow1 {
padding-top: 75px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.seven-cols .col-md-1,
.seven-cols .col-sm-1,
.seven-cols .col-lg-1 {
    width: 100%;
    *width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
.seven-cols .col-md-1,
.seven-cols .col-sm-1,
.seven-cols .col-lg-1 {
    width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
    *width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.seven-cols .col-md-1,
.seven-cols .col-sm-1,
.seven-cols .col-lg-1 {
    width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
    *width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
  }
}
```

And this is how it's looking so far: [Website Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7qLa.png)

*Sorry for not uploading the code into the snippet, tried but couldn't get it to work so hope you guys get the idea anyway... BIG THANKS!*

EDIT:

-ARROWS: [arrow1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqJno.png) [arrow2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17ox3.png) (modified the arrows in the code cause I just realized that arrow1 and arrow3 are the same one... I also want to mention that I gave them a class in order to add some padding to them, so they can look like I showed at the beginning of the post in [Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfq1u.png))

Comment: I'm not sure but what if you make a no-padding-class for your row in your css and then add it to your html? like: .row.no-gutters {margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0;}

Comment: Can you update the arrow image urls in the post?

Comment: @molihua already tried that, it didn't work, and like I said in the post I think that it is cause I set a specific width to the 7 columns in order to make them equal.

Comment: @Highdef what do you mean? do you want me to upload all the icons/arrows into the post?

Comment: @Diamantis Yeah, only the arrows, icons aren't required.

Comment: @Highdef done, already uploaded them, I just realized that arrow1 and 3 were the same so I only uploaded 2 of them and modified the code.

Comment: @Diamantis Posted a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

- Instead of calculating and allocating each item a width, using `flex display` on **seven-cols** and `flex:1` on the **seven-cols divs** to make it flexibly grow and shrink.
- When the max-width reaches a certain width threshold, change the `flex-direction to column` and hide the arrows.

```css
.arrow1 {
  padding-top: 75px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .seven-cols {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .arrow1,
  .arrow2 {
    display:none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .seven-cols {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .seven-cols>* {
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 14%;
  }
  .no-padding .arrow1,
  .no-padding .arrow2 {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="whyus" class="container-fluid text-center">
  <h2>Why Us?</h2>
  <div class="row seven-cols">
    <div class="no-padding">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
      <h4>Passion</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="no-padding">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqJno.png" class="arrow1">
    </div>
    <div class="no-padding">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
      <h4>Ideas</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="no-padding">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/17ox3.png" class="arrow2">
    </div>
    <div class="no-padding">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
      <h4>Work</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="no-padding">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqJno.png" class="arrow1">
    </div>
    <div class="no-padding">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
      <h4>Amazing Results</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  CSS:
```

Comment: This is great! I wasn't aware about this "flex display", I will definitely read about it and thanks for the code man!

Comment: @Diamantis No problem :) https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp